# Set cookie with JWT - NodeJs and Javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt

I'm a bit lost in my own code right now, I need brightness.

I'm trying to set a cookie with JWT when I log in. Here is my code :

My route :

```
router.post('/signin', user.signIn);
```

My controller :

```
const jwtExpire = 3 * 23 * 60 * 60 * 1000
const createToken = (id) => {
    return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: jwtExpire
    })
}

module.exports.signIn = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body

    try {
        const user = await UserModel.login(email, password)
        const token = createToken(user._id)
        res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, jwtExpire })
        res.status(200).json({ user: user._id })
    } catch (err) {
        const errors = signInErrors(err)
        res.status(200).json({ errors })
    }
}
```

My form :

```
<form id="signin-block" style="display: block;" class="p-4 mx-auto">
                    <h2 class="text-center my-4 underline">Se connecter</h2>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                            placeholder="Mot de passe">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4" id="submit">Me connecter</button>
                </form>
```

My function to log in :

```
logInBlock.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const email = e.target[0].value
    const password = e.target[1].value

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/signin',
        data: {
            email: email,
            password: password
        }
    }).then((res) => console.log(res))
})
```

With POSTMAN, the cookie is set. So something is missing is my own request, but I don't see what. Any idea ?

Comment: *With POSTMAN* ... in other words, it's likely to be a CORS error - check the browser developer console for errors, specifically ones that mention CORS

Comment: @Bravo CORS is okay, I have a 200 status. I think my log works fine, just the cookie is not set

Comment: `{ httpOnly: true, jwtExpire }` should probably be `{ httpOnly: true, maxAge: jwtExpire }`. Let us know if this helps.

Comment: OK, so you can't see the cookie in the signin response at all?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Not it does not. The problem is in my axios request, I think I have to set the cookie but I don't see how

Comment: you say you have to "set the cookie in the request"? surely the cookie is set in the response, right? and since it's a httpOnly cookie, you can't access it in the client code at all - but you should see it in the response in the developer tools

Comment: @Bravo no I don't have the cookie in the response. So Why would postman find it and not my request ?

Comment: does the request look identical when using POSTMAN vs your code? i.e. headers, content etc - also, just to be clear - `http://localhost:5000/api/signin` is not a cross origin request is it?

Comment: @Bravo Yes, it is a cross request. Bakend on 5000 and front on 5500. Le request look the same, But POSTMAN set the cookie manualy in the header

Comment: OK, so where are you looking for the cookie? in the browser developer tools, in the response headers shown in the network tab? I'd know where to look in firefox, but I bet you're using chrome or edgeChrome

Comment: I have the response in the console of the chrome the chrome dev tools, with headers, data, config...

Comment: @Bravo In the network tab, when I go to Header, the cookie is here. How to set it as a cookie then ?

Comment: OK, let me ask you this - what makes you think the cookie is NOT set?

Comment: @Bravo When I go to application, then Cookies, all the cookies are listed, but not the JWT cookie

Comment: I think you may need to set "withCredentials" to true

Comment: @Bravo in my axios request in the front ?

Comment: sorry, yes, that's where withCredentials is set, in the request

Comment: @Bravo Ok i'm gonna try with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing this in different origins?  Cookies will not be in request if origins are different, it is unsafe and can lead to attacks.

If yes, another way to do is to response your jwt from server, when ajax is responsed, store your jwt in cookie by client side, and use axios property to bring it in request header:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = yourJwt
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite